# Ignore button click without setting enabled to false?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios5

I have a button that if a circumstance happens I would like for it to be "disabled" without the button getting its alpha reduced. since setting the buttons enabled property to false changes the alpha to about 0.6 I have an if statement set up in the method that gets called then the button is pressed to ignore the rest of the function. The problem is that the button this "dims" when clicked. I would like the button not to change at all, no dimming, no function calling, etc. I want the button to act as if it was disabled but with full alpha. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set userInteraction to false as follows:

```
button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the user interaction property for this

myButton.userInteractionEnabled=YES; // Or No